# Start a new array column after each inner loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, collections

I have a question to a project of mine. I have a Worksheet with 6 columns of data. 1 with dates and 5 with percentages. What I want is to find the dates where the data fall below a certain threshold and then from there find the minimum value and find the length of the period until an empty cell which marks the point where the point where the data value has recovered. I loop over rows and columns and save the data in a collection which add new data to an array (variant()). The problem is that I don't know how to start adding in the next array column after each inner loop. Also I save two inputs the array for each period below each other. A long that gives me the number of days and a string with two dates that shows the period. Ideally they should also be split into their own column (every second input must get to the same column). Alternatively, this second problem might be solved when extracting the array to Excel?

I hope the question is clear and I included all relevant information

Thank you

```
    Dim varDates As Variant, varAll As Variant, varMyArray() As Variant

    dblDDLim = Range("BD8").Value ' the threshold value
    
    Range("BB10").Select
    varDates = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Value ' dates in time series

    Range("BC10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    varAll = Selection.Value ' all data in 5 columns

   ' loops though columns and rows
   For i = LBound(varAll, 2) To UBound(varAll, 2)
        For j = LBound(varAll, 1) To UBound(varAll, 1)
            Cells(9 + j, 54 + i).Select
            If varAll(j, i) <> "" Then
                ReDim Preserve dtTemp(lngCounter)
                dtTemp(lngCounter) = varDates(j, 1)
                
                'data
                ReDim Preserve varTemp(lngCounter): varTemp(lngCounter) = varAll(j, i)
                
                lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            Else
                
                If lngCounter > 0 Then
                                  
                    If WorksheetFunction.Min(varTemp) < dblDDLim Then
                        intMin = IsInArray_Index_oneDim(WorksheetFunction.Min(varTemp), varTemp) ' finds index of the minimum within the period 
                        lngPerLen = UBound(varTemp, 1) - intMin + 1 'length as number of days
                        col.Add lngPerLen ' dynamically add value to the end
                        strRecLen = dtTemp(intMin) & " - " & dtTemp(UBound(dtTemp)) 'recover length as start date to end date
                        col.Add strRecLen
                        lngPerCounter = lngPerCounter + 1 'counts the number of periods
                        varMyArray = Collection2Array(col) 'convert collection to an array
                    End If
                End If
                'counts # of observations in the series
                lngCounter = 0
            End If
            
        Next
    Next


Public Function Collection2Array(col As Collection)
  Dim MyArray() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  ReDim MyArray(0 To col.Count - 1) As Variant
  For i = 1 To col.Count
      MyArray(i - 1) = col(i)
  Next
  Collection2Array = MyArray
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the structure of your data?

Comment: @ElioFernandes I have added a screen shot

Comment: A thought, using a `Dictionary` would behave like a collection, but would enable `Collection2Array` to be replaced by the `.Keys()` or `.Items()' from the dictionary object.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I actually thought about it, but found it a bit too complicated to implement. But I'll give it another shot. It will definitely give me some more optionalities